# split and merge the content

Tags: php, design-patterns, extract

I have content.

```
{this is title1|this is title2}
{this is para11|this is para21}
{this is para12|this is para22}
{this is para13|this is para23}
```

I want to separate these as a two content.

**content 1:**

```
this is title
this is para11
this is para12
this is para13
```

**content 2:**

```
this is title
this is para21
this is para22
this is para23
```

I tried at least to get content 1st in an array but it is not coming.

```
function findinside($start, $end, $string) {
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([^\.)]+)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $string, $m);
    return $m[1];
}
$content = "{this is title1|this is title2}

{this is para11|this is para21}

{this is para12|this is para22}

{this is para13|this is para23}";
$start_string = '{';
$stop_string = '|';
$strings  = findinside($start_string,$stop_string,$content);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($strings);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => this is title1|this is title2}

 {this is para11|this is para21}

 {this is para12|this is para22}

{this is para13
)
```

Can some one help to for 2 content. Also if it will be more than 2 content. I am looking for 2 content now. But if it works for n content that would be ideal. Thanks

Comment: explode by line breaks, loop, explode by pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$content = "{this is title1|this is title2}

{this is para11|this is para21}

{this is para12|this is
para22}

{this is para13|this is para23}{this is para14|this is para24}


{this is 
para14|this is para24}";
#$c = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $content)));
#$c = explode("}{", str_replace(array("}\r", "}\n"), "}", substr($content, 1, -1)));
$c = preg_split("#}\s*{#", substr($content, 1, -1));
$a = array();
foreach($c as $cc){
    $t = explode('|', $cc);
    foreach($t as $k => $v){
        $a[$k][] = $t[$k];
    }
}
var_dump($a[0], $a[1]);#depending on how many items access them by $a[n]
```

Comment: it gives empty array ie (boolean false) for each space between each line.
0 => string 'this is title1' (length=14)
  1 => boolean false
  2 => string 'this is para11' (length=14)

Comment: $content = "{this is title1|this is title2} {While you may be able to get a great rate on . |Check reviews online. Before hiring any new company. } {this is para13|this is para23}";
Returns:
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'this is title1' (length=14)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'this is title2} {While you may be able to get a great rate on .' (length=63)
Not Complete data and }{ is not splited.

Comment: it is showing error in $c=...
str_replace(["\r", "\n"]-->i don't think str_replace take argument like that.and defining blank array $a=[] also show error. i had always changed to $a = array() during testing.

Comment: i think if the separator | is in next line then it escapes it. Those pargraph are missing in output.

Comment: @user2986104 it might have been because I removed all newlines `\r`, `\n` and now I split based on `}any whitespace character[optional]{`

Comment: i want to add one thing here if we can . if there are n number of content. here we have 2 content. And also tell me how to accept the answer.

Comment: it should look like a gray checkmark by my answer. and I updated for `n`

Answer (score 0):

Your character class has to exclude `$end`, because quantifiers are greedy and it will try to match all the way to the last end character, not the first one.

```
function findinside($start, $end, $string) {
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([^\.)' . preg_quote($end) . ']+)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $string, $m);
    return $m[1];
}
```

Comment: working perfect. Can you also suggest me some idea if i have to for n number of content.

Comment: But it doesn't work in my real content. I don't know why. i have reduced the 2nd para of real content. only displays the 1st and last para.
$content = "{this is title1|this is title2}

{While you may be able to get a great rate on .

|Check reviews online. Before hiring any new carpet cleaning company.

}

{this is para13|this is para23}";

Comment: Since the pattern is so regular, why don't you split it into lines with `explode("\n", $content)`, remove the braces from the ends of the lines, then split each line with `explode('|', $line)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$res = preg_split('/\||\}.*\{/Us', substr($content, 1, -1));
for($i=0,$n=1,$l=count($res); $n<$l; $i+=2,$n+=2){
  $content_1[] = $res[$i]; $content_2[] = $res[$n];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't return all the content.you need to put 1 instead of l in for loop and $content_1 returns=>Array ( [0] => this is title1 ) and $content_2 returns =>Array ( [0] => this is title2} {this is para11 )

Answer (score 0):

```
function findinside($start, $end, $middle, $string) {
    $prepare = array();
    $result = array('content_1' => array(), 'content_2' => array());

    $rc = (bool)preg_match_all("/".$start."(.*?)".$end."/", $string, $prepare);
    if($rc){
        foreach ($prepare[1] as $str){
            list($c1, $c2) = explode($middle, $str);
            $result['content_1'][] = $c1;
            $result['content_2'][] = $c2;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Called:

```
$strings = findinside('{', '}', '|', $content);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($strings);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[content_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => this is title1
        [1] => this is para11
        [2] => this is para12
        [3] => this is para13
    )
[content_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => this is title2
        [1] => this is para21
        [2] => this is para22
        [3] => this is para23
    )
)
```

Comment: fails the right result if }{ are near. $content = "{this is title1|this is title2}

{this is para11|this is para21}

{this is para12|this is para22}{this is para13|this is para23}
{this is para14|this is para24}";
And also just return 3 paragraph and didn't return all the paragraph from the real content.

Comment: Fix regExp: **$rc = (bool)preg_match_all("/".$start."(.*?)".$end."/", $string, $prepare);**

Comment: i think if the separator | is in next line then it escapes it. Those paragraph are missing in output.